Flink how to handle Kafka connector failures?
In Apache Flink, how can I catch the exceptions thrown by Kafka Source Connector?
I've a use-case where one of the kafka-clusters which I connect to in my flink application becomes unavailable. If I can catch the exception, I can handle it with some other business logic.
However, it looks like the DataStream constructed from the KafkaSource is lazily evaluated. The error is not thrown until keyBy and process.
Is there a way to catch the exception when I create the source like this?
KafkaSource<List<Event>> kafkaSource = KafkaSourceFactory.createKafkaSource(kafkaTopic, kafkaConfig, deserializationSchema);

return env.fromSource(kafkaSource, watermarkStrategy, uniqueSourceName + "_input")
            .uid(uniqueSourceName + "_input")


Flink distributes the source to multiple TMs, which is why the Kafka consumer doesn't get created until the workflow is being executed remotely. You could run some checks to see if the topic is available in your main method, while constructing the workflow, but there's still a window of time between then and when the workflow actually starts executing.
Would it be possible to use a Failure Enricher (if needed), and then in your main method apply the business logic? You could submit a modified job, for example, in response to a topic failure.
